Is the Berry phase at a degeneracy trivial or non-trivial?
This question is about the original paper on Berry phases by M. Berry (1984). There, the Berry phase $\phi_{B}$ is defined as
$$
\phi_{B}= \oint_\mathcal{C}\underbrace{ \left\langle n(\mathbf{R}) \right | i\nabla_{\mathbf{R}} \left| n(\mathbf{R}) \right \rangle}_{\text{Berry connection } A_n(\mathbf{R})} \cdot d \mathbf{R}.
$$
where $C$ is a closed loop in parameter space with parameters denoted by $\mathbf{R}$ and $\left| n(\mathbf{R}) \right \rangle$ is an instantaneous eigenstate. This integral can be rewritten by using Stokes' theorem, which results in an integral over the surface area that is bounded by the closed loop $C$:
$$
\phi_B = \iint_C \underbrace{\nabla_{\mathbf{R}} \times A_n(\mathbf{R})}_{\text{Berry curvature}} \cdot d\mathbf{S}
$$
So far so good.
In section 3 of the original paper, Berry wanted to apply his newly found formalism to a loop around a degeneracy which can be described in the standard form of a Weyl Hamiltonian:
$$
H = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
z & x - iy\\
x + iy & -z
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which results in a phase of
$$
\exp{\left[i\phi_B(C)\right]} = \exp{\left[-\frac{1}{2}i\Omega(C)\right]}
$$
where $\Omega(C)$ is the solid angle that $C$ subtends at the degeneracy. Berry states that $\Omega(C)$ only changes in multiples of $4\pi$.
There are two things that I don't quite understand:

"Multiples of $4\pi$" seems to imply that the integral was taken over the whole sphere. Looking at the equations above, the surface integral should be performed over a surface that is bounded by the contour $C$, which is usually not a closed manifold such as a sphere.
Given that there is another factor of 1/2 in the exponent, "multiples of $4\pi$" would imply that I will get the same trivial phase whether I go around the loop or not, namely $e^0=e^{-i2\pi}=1$. I find that strange since the Hamiltonian above is the very definition of a Weyl node which should give us topologically non-trivial behavior, and therefore these two cases should be distinguishable.


I think what Berry means is that for a given $C$, one can define two solid angles ("inside" and "outside"), whose $\Omega$ differs just by $4\pi$. So $e^{-i\Omega(C)/2}$ is well-defined, independent of the choice.
